# Greater Feint Clarification

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats

I don't understand the benefits of `Greater Feint` feat in Pathfinder.

Its **Benefit** states:

> Whenever you use feint to cause an opponent to lose his Dexterity bonus, he loses that bonus until the beginning of your next turn, in addition to losing his Dexterity bonus against your next attack.

Since *feinting* is a move action, how many attacks am I allowed to perform after a feint? Just one or maybe two if I wield two weapons?

Can you describe some scenario in which `Greater Feint` gives some advantage thanks to its extended Dexterity-loss duration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The benefit to *you* is relatively minimal, since attacks of opportunity are the only way you're likely to be making additional attacks against the target before your next turn. Not the only way, but the most likely way, and not very likely at that. As C. Ross pointed out, while Hero points are few & far between, `Greater Feint` can really help them hit hard.

The benefit to the *rest* of your party is a turn of the target not getting their Dex bonus; rogues in particular will be appreciative of the free sneak attacks this gives them.

Remember that denying a target their Dex bonus is *not* the same as making them flat-footed; they can still make attacks of opportunity, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider Two-Weapon Feint if it works for you. It lets you feint by sacrificing one of your attacks when Two-Weapon Fighting.

There's also an Improved Two-Weapon Feint, but Greater Feint makes it redundant. Improved Two-Weapon denies Dex until the end of your turn, while Greater denies Dex until your next turn. The reason Improved Two-Weapon Feint isn't totally worthless is that Two-Weapon Feint is not a prerequisite, so you can almost get the effect of Greater Feint and Two-Weapon Feint in one feat.